# Registering Help Book in Qt app

Tags: c++, qt, macos, menu, helpfile

I am building a Qt application on Mac OS X and I decided to create a Help book. I attempted to use the [official docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_intro/user_assistance_intro.html), but the help book does not appear in the help menu.

The help book is located in `my.app/Contents/Resources/HC.help/`. It itself seems fine, I tried opening it directly with HelpViewer.app and it opened just fine.

This is how I am registering it in `my.app/Contents/Info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleHelpBookFolder</key>
<string>HC.help</string>
<key>CFBundleHelpBookName</key>
<string>com.houbysoft.hc.help</string>
```

It still doesn't show up in my application's Help menu. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's been five years since this question was asked, but I just worked out how to do it so I figured I'd share my findings.

In addition to adding the keys @houbysoft mentioned to Info.plist, it was also necessary to manually add a menu item to the Help menu that invoked Help Viewer.

So example code (in the initialization of a QMainWindow):

```
QMenu *helpMenu = new QMenu("Help", menuBar());
helpMenu->addAction(tr("&XYZ Help..."), this, SLOT(showHelp()));
```

(Or you can add the menu item some other way, perhaps using Designer.)

The showHelp() method:

```
void openHelp()
{
    CFBundleRef appBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

    if (appBundle == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    CFStringRef myBookName = (CFStringRef)CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(appBundle, CFSTR("CFBundleHelpBookName"));

    if (!myBookName || CFGetTypeID(myBookName) != CFStringGetTypeID()) {
        return;
    }

    AHLookupAnchor(myBookName, CFSTR("Start"));
}
```

Note that I added an anchor named "Start" on the first page of my documentation. Replace `"Start"` with the name of your own anchor.